# create a nested dictionary based on panda dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I have a dataframe like this

```
data = np.zeros((3,), dtype=[('A', 'a10'), ('B', 'f4'), ('C', 'f4')])
data[:] = [('key1', 1, 2), ('key2', 3, 4), ('key3', 5, 6)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

and I want to convert it to a dictionary of dataframes which the first column would be the key of dictionary. How can I create such a dictionary?

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
data = np.zeros((3,), dtype=[('A', 'a10'), ('B', 'f4'), ('C', 'f4')])
data[:] = [('key1', 1, 2), ('key2', 3, 4), ('key3', 5, 6)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

`df`:

```
         A  B  C
0  b'key1'  1  2
1  b'key2'  3  4
2  b'key3'  5  6
```

Conversion:

```
df.set_index('A').T.to_dict()
```

Result:

```
{b'key1': {'B': 1.0, 'C': 2.0},
 b'key2': {'B': 3.0, 'C': 4.0},
 b'key3': {'B': 5.0, 'C': 6.0}}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, this helps a lot

Comment: Almost four years later this is so clutch and helped me with something. Thank you!